# What is the need to do sharding of TFRecords files?

Tags: tensorflow

Why TFRecords file is sharded in the inception model example in TensorFlow ?

For randomness, can't the list of files be shuffled before creating one single TFRecord file ?

Comment: I suspect it's done so that you can have multiple read threads running in parallel. But you're right in general, so long as you can read from one file fast enough to keep your GPU (or 8) busy.

Comment: If it shuffled before creating a single TFRecord file, then during training you can only get local randomness based on the shuffle capacity. But when you have multiple shards, you can shuffle the shards while training and get much better randomness in shuffling. And this also helps in distributed training.

Answer (score 7):

**Why TFRecords file is sharded in the inception model example in TensorFlow ?**

According to [object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md), there are two advantages in sharding your dataset:

1. Files can be read in parallel, improving data loading speed
2. Examples can be shuffled better by sharding

You probably already knew the second point as it is in your second question:

**For randomness, can't the list of files be shuffled before creating one single TFRecord file ?**

Shuffling the dataset before creating the record is indeed a good practice because shuffling a TFRecord can only be done partially. Indeed, you can only load a certain number of examples in memory. The shuffling is then done by selecting randomly your next example among the ones in memory. You can see more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028683/whats-going-on-in-tf-train-shuffle-batch-and-tf-train-batch)

However, if you only shuffle the dataset when creating the record, your network will always see examples in the same order in the successive training epochs. This might result in unwanted convergence behaviours due to the random order that was given once and for all. It is thus more interesting to shuffle the dataset on the fly to have different orderings in different epochs.

Sharding your dataset can easen the shuffling. Instead to be forced to always read in the same order from the same one file, you can start to read a bit from each file, choosing at random.