# tensorflow API detection boxes and evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to use the API detection on tensorflow following this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9 . But there are some details I am not understanding.

First, I do not understand some parameters for the evaluation in the config file. "num readers" and "max_evals" parameters. "Max evals" seems to be the number of evaluation on the dataset but why it is not 1 by default ? Because we need to test only one time the checkpoint (or I am wrong ?). Regarding the training, are the data shuffle automatically ?

Second, I am wondering if we can use tensorboard so as to display the box in an image during the training WITH the API detection. If yes, what are the steps to obtain it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `num_readers`: I' not entirely sure, but it probably has something to do with how many processes you'll need to read the eval input. You could try and change it if you see that reading the data is really where you're losing time (it's usually not the case though, inference takes more time).
- `max_evals`: says how many checkpoints you want to evaluate. While training, the trianing job will save checkpoints regularly (so that if you stop the training, you don't lose all the previous work, for instance; or so that you can choose between the networks created respectively by `n` and `m` iterations). You'll usually start an evaluation job at the same time, which will regularly evaluate the last created checkpoint, up to `max_evals` checkpoints. If you don't fill this value, it will evaluate all created checkpoints, thus providing you an evaluation performance regularly during training.
- about shuffling the training data: you need to add `shuffle: True` to the train input reader (in the config file) for that, but [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937410/7456923) it may not work on the first epoch, so you should probably also make sure your dataset is not sorted beforehand.
- to dispay images with boxes during training: yes you can. You'll need to run the evaluation job for that. You can set how many images will be saved in the config file. To see the evolution of the detections for these images, you'll need `shuffle: False` in your eval input reader. Otherwise it will show you different images at every step, so you won't really see the progress. Then you just run Tensorboard, the images will be in the "images" tab.

Comment: Thank for the answer ! What do you mean by "epoch" ? When I look the config file, I found only the number of step. Is it a parameter to add ?

Comment: Yes you can add it, just like on the eval input reader part. An "epoch" is "going through all the data once" (so if you have n input images, and you train for m steps, you'll do m/n epochs in total). The training data will be re-shuffled at the start of each epoch excecpt the first one.

Comment: Thank for the help ! Do you have a link regarding all the parameters we can use in the config file? I find only limited documentation. For the epoch parameter, do I have to put "epoch : 100" for example in the training input ?

Comment: Unfortunately I think there is no unified doc for all the parameters in the config file, you have to dig through the code to find things. You don't need to set the number of epochs here, you set the number of training steps (with `num_steps: 100` in the training config), which is actually more meaningful.

Comment: Actually there is some info there, though not meant as a documentation: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/train.proto  (and similar files for eval, input readers, etc)

Comment: Thank you I will take a look !